# Use Navigate function not working (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm following a tutorial and everything was going great until I tried to implement Navigation through a search input. For instance, If I am on http://localhost:3000/searched/profile. Typing out an input of 'names' in the search bar should take me to http://localhost:3000/searched/names. In the tutorial it worked that way and I believe I did the same thing but it doesn't work for me

First below is the Search component for the search bar and its input

And then the Pages where my routing is done. My Browser Router is in the App.js.

```
import styled from "styled-components"
import { FaSearch } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { useState } from 'react'
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'

function Search() {

  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate('/searched/' + input) (I GUESS THIS IS WHAT IS NOT WORKING)
  };

  return (
    <FormStyle onSubmit={submitHandler}>
    <div>
    <FaSearch></FaSearch>
    <input onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} type="text" value={input}/>
    </div>
    <h1>{input}</h1>
    </FormStyle>
  )
}

const FormStyle = styled.div`
  margin: 0 20rem;

  div{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  input{
    border: none;
    background: linear-gradient(35deg, #494949, #313131);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
  }
  svg{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(100%, -50%);
    color: white;
  }
`

export default Search
```

Pages

```
import Home from "./Home"
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Cuisine from "./Cuisine"
import Searched from "./Searched"


function Pages() {

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
      <Route path='/cuisine/:type' element={<Cuisine/>} />
      <Route path='/searched/:search'  element={<Searched/>} />
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default Pages
```

Comment: what `:search` mean, is it a query parameter or dynamic value?

Comment: Please include all relevant code you are working with. Where is the `Search` component rendered? What is the `Searched` component that is handling the `search` route path param? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: FWIW I'm unable to reproduce the issue as you describe in this running [condesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-navigate-function-not-working-react-livifv).

Comment: You see here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router

Comment: @DharmikPatel Thank you for your response. Yes it is a dynamic value for the search input. I might not be doing it the best way and I'm open to suggestions. Thank you again

Comment: @DharmikPatel `":search"` is a route path parameter, nothing to do with queryString parameters. It's meant to be dynamic for dynamic path matching. In other words, whatever the value is in the URL path for *that* segment, it will be assigned to a route param named `search`.

Comment: Were you able to check my sandbox to see what may be different from your actual code? Feel free to fork my sandbox and add in more of your code to make it a more accurate facsimile until it reproduces the issue, if it does.

Comment: @DrewReese  Thank you for your response. Yeah I did and it works perfectly but I'm trying to figure out how to implement into my program. Did my code not work because I didn't add useParams for the search value ?

Comment: Dunno since I can't see the `Searched` component rendered on the `path='/searched/:search'` route, but perhaps yes, since you'd need to use the `useParams` hook *somewhere* to access the route params.

Comment: @DrewReese https://github.com/ddboy19912/Deliciso-React-.git

Comment: Ok, I've forked your repo into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-dewdney-9vp3rl?file=/src/components/Search.jsx). What are the exact steps to reproduce the issue? The `Search` component appears to also have the same issue I found in your snippet above where the form needs to be a styled `form` element instead of a `div` so the form submission works.

Comment: @DrewReese Hey, I've update the code on github but the search input is still not working. When I search a name like cookies. It is supposed to take me to http://localhost:3000/searched/cookies but it does nothing when I press 'Enter'. but when I add the /searched/cookies from the homepage it does what its supposed to do and displays all the relevant cookie searches from the API.

Comment: Do you know what the problem might be ?

Comment: I don't know what you changed in your repo, but your code still has the same issue... the form needs to be a styled `form` element instead of a `div` so the form submission works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FormStyle` component is a styled `div` element instead of a `form` element, so the `onSubmit` handler is meaningless on the `div`. To resolve you should use the `form` element so the form submission works as you are expecting.

`Search.js` Example:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { FaSearch } from "react-icons/fa";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Search() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate("/searched/" + input);
  };

  return (
    <FormStyle onSubmit={submitHandler}> // <-- (2) onSubmit works now
      <div>
        <FaSearch></FaSearch>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
          value={input}
        />
      </div>
      <h1>{input}</h1>
    </FormStyle>
  );
}

const FormStyle = styled.form` // <-- (1) switch to form element
  margin: 0 20rem;

  div {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  input {
    border: none;
    background: linear-gradient(35deg, #494949, #313131);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
  }
  svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(100%, -50%);
    color: white;
  }
`;

export default Search;
```

[image: Edit use-navigate-function-not-working-react]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but I had the same issue while following the same tutorial.

I found the issue wasn't on either of the pages you showed above. My issue was on the App.js page. I originally put the Search Component above my BrowserRouter. Once I moved it into the Browser Router component the error stopped and the pages worked as they should.